# Cmake, .lib, dll and avoiding multiple .lib copies inside binary

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, cmake

All in all, what I want is to avoid duplicate .lib files in several .dlls since the generated .dlls will be used together in a .exe file and this makes global state duplicated in the .lib file duplicated.

**Concrete Problem**:

I have a project with 3 libraries and one .exe:

- libDependentA.dll
- libDependentB.dll
- libIndependent.lib -- static library

The dependencies are as follow:

- libDependentA.dll -- depends on -> libIndependent.lib
- libDependentB.dll -- depends on -> libIndependent.lib

I have an .exe. Depends on both libDependentA.dll and libDependentB.dll

This makes two copies of my .lib into the .exe, which is what is causing problems.

**Solutions?**

- Preferred solution. Don't know if possible, when googling no info.

Make a .dll out of the `libIndependent.lib`. How can I do this? I couldn't make a dll out of .lib files in cmake through `add_libary(newdllfromlib SHARED)`. It has no source files dependencies and I tried to `target_link_libraries` into 
`newdllfromlib`. Is there an easy way without using empty source files or other tricks?

- Make `libDependentB.dll` depend only in `libDependentA.dll` and remove `libIndependent.lib` from `libDependentB.dll`. How can I do that in cmake? The problem here seems to be that cmake transitively propagates to all the other places `libIndependent.lib`, including the .exe, if it appears in `target_link_libraries(libDependentA...`. If I add `LINK_PRIVATE`, then, I cannot set up the configuration I want in cmake, because I must link `libIndependent.lib` again into the `libDependentB.dll`. Anyway to do it?

Comment: Do you have source files of libIndependent.lib?

Comment: Just the headers. I am on it now, but, how can I, anyway, dllexport the symbols? I shouldn't change that source headers code anyway.

Comment: What about wrapping all the static libs into a single dll, e.g. called core.dll and then have all you dlls link with core.dll?

Comment: @Andre the static libs are not dllexported (the headers contain no symbol export). Will this work? What are actually several well known ways of avoiding duplicated symbols in .lib files linked to .dlls?

Comment: No, that won't work, which is why I replied as a comment and not an answer. But you can create a dllexported "passthrough wrapper" in your core.dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplication of symbols in .dlls from linked static libraries is what static libraries are supposed to do. If the static library `libIndependent` is 3rd party code, then the developers of `libIndependent` probably have some reason why they chosen the static library and not a dynamic library.

If you use symbols from `libIndependent` in both `libDependentA` and `libDependentB` and you do not have source code of `libIndependent`, the short answer is that you cannot do it directly. Static libraries are usually build with different set of flags/defines than shared libraries (most obvious is exporting the symbols `dllexport` / `dllimport` as you noted). You can export some `libIndependent` symbols from `libDependentA` by [def file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh.aspx). But usually only symbols that are used in dll are present in the library (`libDependentA`) and you can run into various other problems.

However you can create a shared library wrapper `libIndependentWrapper.dll`, where you create a wrapper function for every function from `libIndependent` you need. The wrapper functions would have new header with `dllexport` / `dllimport`.

Comment: I already thought of the wrapper approach. Too cumbersome. I think I should see if we can get .dlls.